# Create docker container, execute a script and delete the container

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, swarm

I want a command that, in first, will create a docker container, then execute a sql command on my database and then delete the container when it's done.

For the moment I have this Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# copy database-file.sh
WORKDIR /database-file
RUN mkdir database-file
COPY * /database-file/

# Update and install mysql-client
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install mysql-client

# Prepare database-prepare script to be use
RUN chmod +x ./database-prepare.sh

VOLUME /app/log

# Exec my script
ENTRYPOINT ["./database-prepare.sh"]
```

I took an Ubuntu image, I don't know if it's the best but for the moment, it's ok i think. I just want to test.

So there is my script :

```
### Global ./database-prepare.sh ###

#!/bin/bash

# Get service name by Docker secret.
service=$(cat /run/secrets/<society_name>_DATABASE_PREPARE__SERVICE)
# Format the service name.
serviceName=${service//./-}

# Clone the repo of my service
git clone --recurse-submodules git@bitbucket.org:<society_name>/<society_name>.binding.$service.git /$serviceName

# CD in the right folder
cd /$serviceName/build/

# Prepare my script and execute it
chmod +x database-prepare.sh
./database-prepare.sh
```

Then each service have his own database-prepapre.sh that will create a new user in my database :

```
### Service ./database-prepare.sh ###

#!/bin/bash

# Get password with Docker secret
<society_name>_MSQL_ROOT_PWD=$(cat /run/secrets/<society_name>_MYSQL_PWD) # My Mysql password
<society_name>_BINDING_ABEEWAY_GENERIC_DBS__<society_name>_DATA__PWD=$(cat /run/secrets/<society_name>_BINDING_ABEEWAY_GENERIC_DBS__<society_name>_DATA__PWD) # My password for this user

mysql -h <society_name>-sql-server.mysql.database.azure.com --user='administrateur@<society_name>-sql-server' --ssl --password=$<society_name>_MYSQL_ROOT_PWD << EOF
DROP USER IF EXISTS '<society_name>.binding.abeeway.generic'@'%';
CREATE USER '<society_name>.binding.abeeway.generic'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$<society_name>_BINDING_ABEEWAY_GENERIC_DBS__<society_name>_DATA__PWD';

GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON <society_name>_data.ms_gpsposition TO '<society_name>.binding.abeeway.generic'@'%';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON <society_name>_data.ms_log TO '<society_name>.binding.abeeway.generic'@'%';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON <society_name>_data.ms_temperature TO '<society_name>.binding.abeeway.generic'@'%';
EOF
```

And know here is my issue :

```
./database-prepare.sh: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./database-prepare.sh: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

So my error is in the file of my Service, where I have "End Of File" text. I try to execute this code, directly in a running container and there is no problem with the EOF... I don't really know where I make a mistake, I'm a novice in Dockerfile, and I think my mistake it's maybe caused by the Image I took, or I maybe I forgot to install a useful tool to make my script work correctly. Or just my script isn't good .. I don't know.

I hope you have enough information to help me, tell me if you need more.
Thank you very much !

Ps: If you know how to delete my service after he executed his command, I would be grateful ! I work on swarm cluster

Comment: Quote your variables. The passwords might contain, spaces, quotation marks or other script-unfriendly characters.

Comment: Can you run `mysql` directly from the host, bypassing all of this setup?

Comment: @micke Thanks for your idea, unfortunately, I try your solution and that's doesn't help.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah, that would be more easy, but I can't do this, cause all my passwords are stocked by docker secret, so there are accessible only in a container. That's why I need to create one container, get the password I want and delete the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution, I rewrite my Dockerfile with another image :

```
FROM alpine:3.7 # <----- Changed

WORKDIR /database-file
RUN mkdir database-file
COPY * /database-file/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install mysql-client # <----- Deleted
RUN apk add mysql-client # <----- Added
RUN apk add git # <----- Added
RUN apk add openssh-client # <----- Added

RUN chmod +x ./database-prepare.sh
VOLUME /app/log

ENTRYPOINT ["sh","./database-prepare.sh"] # <----- Changed
```

I think the real problem was my ENTRYPOINT, after reflection I think my old ENTRYPOINT doesn't call correctly my script.

I hope this will help another person.